Cannot sum the value from Google sheet with QUERY and IMPORTRANGE
I have a Google sheet with the budget details, another one is the summary, I have no idea why the first-row value cannot be summed if I
QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("....", "Sheet1!A1:O"), "SELECT...")

if I
QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("....", "Sheet1!A2:O"), "SELECT...") -- incorrect calculation

Below are the Google sheets
Bduget Details
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Km2LF40pKqFddcO7rAulauycRvb8Jb7LVutrxeyB2jU/edit#gid=0
Budget Review
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w3eLObqywfNYGoWmhQFr35e1y7gzizAlR2ao9ifFsm0/edit#gid=1989469577
From the Summary!E1 is calculated as 204,500 but Summary_v2!E1 is 266,500
value 266,500 is correct. Is there any bug from Google Sheet?

As the first contains the value, if I
QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("....", "Sheet1!A1:O"), "SELECT...")

without the 3rd parameter header, the query considers the first row is text format, so the sum doesn't include the value.
Correct query statement should be
QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("....", "Sheet1!A1:O"), "SELECT...", 0)

Reference website: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en

use 3rd query parameter
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("....", "Sheet1!A1:O"), "SELECT...", 0)


